# How do you execute a global command in a vimscript function?

Tags: vim, nerdtree, neovim

How do I write a function that executes the :NERDTree commands? Note: I am using neovim but i'm assuming the vimscript syntax is the same

here is my code

```
nmap <expr> <C-n> Toggle()

func Toggle()
  if g:open == 0
    let g:open += 1
    execute g:NERDTreeCWD
  else
    let g:open -= 1
    execute g:NERDTreeClose
endfunc
```

Comment: You don't need [`execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) because you don't do evaluation. And you need `()`. So: `g:NERDTreeCWD()` and `g:NERDTreeClose()`.

Comment: And you dont need `g:` for functions, only for variables (see `help :g`). So: `NERDTreeCWD()`

Answer (score 2):

The NERDTree commands are *custom Ex commands*, so you invoke them (interactively) via `:NERDTreeCWD` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In a Vimscript, you can drop the `:` prefix.

Maybe part of the confusion (also seen in the comments) arises from the fact that the NERDTree commands are implemented by global functions with the same name:

```
:verbose command NERDTreeCWD
    Name              Args Address Complete    Definition
|   NERDTreeCWD       0                        call NERDTreeCWD()
```

So you could also bypass the custom function and `call NERDTreeCWD()` directly, but this would make you depend on implementation details of the plugin, and is therefore discouraged.

#### Implementing NERDTree toggling

Are you aware that the plugin already has a [`:NERDTreeToggle`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/72c3656799289d4635520c28e17f737066ce19d6/doc/NERDTree.txt#L123-L126) command?

Also, you don't need to define your own flag variable (`g:open`) - just reuse the one from the plugin (exposed via the `g:NERDTree.IsOpen()` function). Yes, this makes you depend on plugin details (but this looks like a public API, not internal implementation, so it should be far more stable) - it's still better than trying to reinvent the wheel. (Your global flag would have problems with multiple tab pages - each could have a NERDTree active or not.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful info. What I should have explained earlier is that i'm trying to workaround a problem with :NERDTreeToggle where the command opens a second unwanted tree of the parent dir that lingers after toggling. The idea was to use NERDTreeCWD because it does not spawn the unwanted parent tree. I tried using `call NERDTreeCWD()`  however I get this error `E523: Not allowed here`.